# Element 'body' : Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content is 'element-only' after Magento 2.3.4 upgrade

Tags: layout, magento-upgrade, custom-theme, magento2.3.4, product-details

After **Magento 2.3.4** upgrade, **Error** is **"Element 'body' : Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content is 'element-only'"** on Product details page.

> Actually after removing below code from
>   app/code/Vendor/Module/view/layout/catalog_product_view.xml file it's
>   resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <!-- <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>   ---->
   </body>
</page>
```

Error screen:
[image]

> Now i am looking for rectification of this code because it was working
>   fine in Magento 2.2.4 version but not in Magento 2.3.4
>
> If anyone having an idea please guide me. Thanks in Advance !!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Below code worked perfectly fine.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
          <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
          <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" template="Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
      </body>
  </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setTemplate is not used in Magento 2.3.4 you double check with that.

Try with below code

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Hi @aravind, i tried this solutions before only actually error resolved but template was not loading.

Comment: As per Magento 2.3.4 std. action method is deprecated so that's why error was coming.

Comment: sorry action node